# Can't change object property for Vue component (a true anomaly)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, clone

A strange anomaly. An object/component property `this.gridTiles` does get set correctly when I do the "undo" action first. But then when I perform the "redo" action (see code below), I'm unable to set `this.gridTiles` to the new value! It seems to be holding on to the old value. `this.gridTiles` is an array with nested items/objects. Right before I try to set the value though, it's giving me the correct value if I assign it to a `test` variable. Very strange! Any help would be much appreciated!

Note : cloneDeep() is enabled by this package : [https://www.npmjs.com/package/clone-deep]

ComponentA.vue

```
    data() {
        return {
            gridTiles: [],
        }
    },

....

        setCurrentEntireState(historyParams) {
            let test = cloneDeep(historyParams.gridTiles); // CORRECT VALUE
            this.test = cloneDeep(historyParams.gridTiles); // we can set this arbitrary object property correctly
            //this.gridTiles = test;    // doesn't work
            //delete this.gridTiles;    // doesn't help even if we do this first
            this.gridTiles = cloneDeep(historyParams.gridTiles); // WRONG VALUE, WHY ??
        },

        getCurrentEntireState() {  // used in saving historyStack items, not shown
            return {
                gridTiles: cloneDeep(this.gridTiles)
            }
        },

....

        EventBus.$on('refreshHistoryStateForReceiptMap', (historyParams) => {
            this.setCurrentEntireState(historyParams);
            ....
        })
```

ComponentB.vue

```
    methods: {

        ....

        undoHistoryAction() {
            let historyParams = this.$store.getters.historyStack[this.$store.getters.historyIndex - 1];
            EventBus.$emit('refreshHistoryStateForReceiptMap', historyParams);

            this.$store.commit('historyIndexDecrement');
        },

        redoHistoryAction() {
            let historyParams = this.$store.getters.historyStack[this.$store.getters.historyIndex];
            EventBus.$emit('refreshHistoryStateForReceiptMap', historyParams);

            this.$store.commit('historyIndexIncrement');
        }
    },
```

Comment: Be careful of arrow functions with 'this' keyword inside of them. an arrow function doesn't use it the same way a `function()` does. From the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):```although without its own bindings to the this, arguments, super, or new.target keywords. Arrow function expressions are ill suited as methods, and they cannot be used as constructors.```

Comment: Hmm when I log `this` to console it shows me the correct component (Component A). Or would this still be misleading?

Comment: Tried converting it to a non-arrow function... no difference.

Comment: Just tried operating on another set of data and the same thing happens, it always gets set to an older value, not the one I'm trying to set it to.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the correct answer and should maybe be a comment, but is too long to be a comment so I'll post here. Hopes this helps:

The code:

```
        setCurrentEntireState(historyParams) {
            let test = cloneDeep(historyParams.gridTiles); // CORRECT VALUE
            this.test = cloneDeep(historyParams.gridTiles); // we can set this arbitrary object property correctly
            //this.gridTiles = test;    // doesn't work
            //delete this.gridTiles;    // doesn't help even if we do this first
            this.gridTiles = cloneDeep(historyParams.gridTiles); // WRONG VALUE, WHY ??
        },
```

gets wrong every line that uses `this`. I would bet that this code:

```
 EventBus.$on('refreshHistoryStateForReceiptMap', (historyParams) => {
            this.setCurrentEntireState(historyParams);
            ....
        })
```

Is somehow messing with the `this` context. Maybe is placed inside a callback so it loses the `this` context of the component?

You should log `this` inside `setCurrentEntireState` to check if it really is the component.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes I did log `this` and confirmed that it is indeed the correct Component A. Another clue is that it correctly update `this.gridTiles` during the "undo" (the step before the "redo"). Even if if it was another component, I should be able to set it to a given value and log it right after, and that value should stick, no? Which is not the case here. Help....

Comment: Also that last block of code you mentioned is sitting inside the correct Component A. Same with the method `setCurrentEntireState`. So we would expect `this` to be correct too.

Answer (score 1):

The console.log() was showing a different value than when I actually used the Chrome JS debugger with a breakpoint. Also, I investigated further downstream and found that some other custom code was reverting the value back to the old/original one. The moral of the story, console.log() might not always be correct, or there might be some lag?